# How can I create stored procedure from within Python script?

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cx-oracle

I am looking to way to create an oracle stored procedure in Python.

I know, `cursor.callproc` in *cx_Oracle* exists to call the existing stored procedure, but I am looking for a way/method to create an Oracle stored procedure in Python.

Comment: What did you try or research? Building stored procedures is just running SQL or plsql code which you can run in Python or any database connected language (Java, PHP, C#, etc.).

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `execute()` with the SQL `CREATE OR REPLACE` command.

To check if the procedure was valid, you need to query a base table like `user_errors`.

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""create or replace procedure x(a in number) as begin BOGUS end;""")
    cursor.execute("""
            select name, type, line, position, text
            from user_errors
            where name = 'X'
            order by name, type, line, position""")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
```

The output is:

```
[('X', 'PROCEDURE', 1, 41, 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:\n\n   := . ( @ % ;\nThe symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.\n')]
```

We are looking at how a future version of cx_Oracle can directly expose Oracle's 'success with info' flag and the compilation error message.

Comment: This does not seem to work when its a multiline procedure ?

Comment: Works for me :)  Did you use triple quotes?  Open a new question with behavior details if you still have a problem.